# What does "Emit" mean in the context of .Net Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

What does `Emit` mean in .Net, is it the same as the meaning of "Generate Code"?

For instance, if I were designing a class with a function that returned some code it produced, what name would be semantically more correct `MyClass.EmitCode()` or `MyClass.GenerateCode()`?

What do I need to understand in .Net?

Comment: @Mishax apologies if my edit has distorted your meaning.

Comment: It was closed because it will attract answers based entirely on opinion, not because it lacks code or is off topic for SO.  Edit the question such that it asks for factual answers, not just which name is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the English language level, the word "emit" is essentially "to give out", "to produce" - so *in that sense* it is reasonable to use as a synonym with "generate". There may be some confusion, however, between this general usage of "emit", vs a very specific usage, i.e. `System.Reflection.Emit` - the latter refers to *IL generation*, not code generation.

In your case, since you are including the word "code", i.e. `EmitCode()`, then I'm not sure that this ambiguity exists. I'm not sure, therefore, whether there is a strong case to be made for or against the use of the word "emit" here. Frankly, as long as you document *what the method does*, I'm not sure it matters hugely ;p